# Best index for table with dynamic predicate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to optimize the query speed from the following table in SQL Server

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PriceNodeLookupIndex]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PriceNodeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ItemId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OptionValueId1] [int] NULL,
    [OptionValueId2] [int] NULL,
    [OptionValueId3] [int] NULL,
    [OptionValueId4] [int] NULL,
    [OptionValueId5] [int] NULL,
    [OptionValueId6] [int] NULL,
    [OptionValueId7] [int] NULL,
    [OptionValueId8] [int] NULL,
    [OptionValueId9] [int] NULL,
    [OptionValueId10] [int] NULL,
    [OptionValueId11] [int] NULL,
    [OptionValueId12] [int] NULL,
    [OptionValueId14] [int] NULL,
    [OptionValueId15] [int] NULL,
    [OptionValueId13] [int] NULL,
    [OptionValueId16] [int] NULL,
    [OptionValueId17] [int] NULL,
    [OptionValueId18] [int] NULL,
    [OptionValueId19] [int] NULL,
    [OptionValueId20] [int] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_PriceNodeLookupIndex] 
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
)
```

The queries that are run against this table are like this:

```
SELECT PriceNodeId 
FROM PriceNodeLookupIndex 
WHERE ItemId = 2345
  AND OptionValueId5 = 63423
  AND OptionValueId11 = 97543
  AND OptionValueId13 = 39452
```

However, the `OptionValueId` predicate list is dynamically generated so that it can be any combination of `OptionValueId` columns.

Therefore the next query could be

```
SELECT PriceNodeId 
FROM PriceNodeLookupIndex     
WHERE ItemId = 2345
  AND OptionValueId7 = 45340
  AND OptionValueId14 = 5693
```

Only one of any column will ever be used in a query.

The current indexes are

- Non-clustered index on `Id`
- Clustered index on `PriceNodeId`

and:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [PriceNodeLookupIndex_All] 
ON [dbo].[PriceNodeLookupIndex] ([ItemId] ASC)
INCLUDE ([OptionValueId1], [OptionValueId2], [OptionValueId3],
         [OptionValueId4], [OptionValueId5], [OptionValueId6],
         [OptionValueId7], [OptionValueId8], [OptionValueId9],
         [OptionValueId10], [OptionValueId11], [OptionValueId12],
         [OptionValueId13], [OptionValueId14], [OptionValueId15],
         [OptionValueId16], [OptionValueId17], [OptionValueId18],
         [OptionValueId19], [OptionValueId20])
```

When I run the execution plan, it is using the big index but also suggests and targeted index that would only work for that exact combinations of `OptionValueId` columns (not useful for me).

This entire application performance it determined by the speed of these queries.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might increase the speed of these queries or is this as good as it gets?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: A clustered index on ItemId would probably be the most useful.

Comment: Using MS SQL Server

Comment: Stu, You are saying to add a clustered index to ItemId and drop the big index?

Comment: Possibly, it all depends on your data; I would suggest a properly normalised design, having 20 "option" columns is a flawed structure - what if you needed 200, or 2000? You should have a single column and store values as rows - then an index can be used to seek directly to the required row(s)

Comment: there's no point indexing PriceNodeId if you're only selecting it and not filtering on it

Comment: including all those columns in the ItemId index will make your index nearly as big as the table itself.  I agree with Stu, just create the clustered index on ItemId and then the dbms can scan the rest of the conditions on that subset of the table

Comment: SQL Server is notorious for suggesting not-very-useful `include` type indexes. I agree with the other comment that the first step in performance tuning is using a properly normalised table design. I also agree that probably the biggest perf improvement is creating a clustered index on `ItemId` since it's always in your query goign by the column name probably drastically reduces candidate rows.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are violating the first normal form of database modeling (by a devious means - the apocope), you cannot optimize such queries.

**First** you should renormalize your model by externalizing this pseudo array (OptionValueId1 ... OptionValueId20) into a table like :

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.PriceNodeLookupIndex_values
(   Id int        NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.PriceNodeLookupIndex ON DELETE CASCADE,
    Position      INT NOT NULL,
    OptionValue   INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT    PK_PriceNodeLookupIndex_values PRIMARY KEY(Id, Position));
CREATE INDEX X ON dbo.PriceNodeLookupIndex_values (OptionValue);
```

**Second**, remove all the OptionValueId1 ... OptionValueId20 of your original table.

**Third** create a view with a pivot operator to simulate your abnormalized table. As an exemple you should give the name "dbo.PriceNodeLookupIndex2" for this view.

**Last**, test the speed of the query rewrited for dbo.PriceNodeLookupIndex2.

Every time you will not respects the spirit of data modeling concets like normal forms, perfomances will be ugly...

If you want user that can INSERT or UPDATE the view, write two INSTEAD OF triggers that will do the job seamlessly.

Especially in your original table many columns will have NULL values (in fact a marker) that is almost 4 bytes without values... The result will be an obese table with a lot of empty thing that will lower the performances also.

By the way, why a NONCLUSTERED Primary Key for the PriceNodeLookupIndex ? Do you like to shoot yourself in the foot ?

Another way that I do not recommend is to have a CLUSTERED COLUMSTORE INDEX for your original table...

As a complement (but in french... later it will be in english) with the SQL commands :
[Modélisation : viol de la première forme normale par « apocope »](http://mssqlserver.fr/modelisation-viol-de-la-premiere-forme-normale-par-apocope/)

For fun, the view that is the exact equivalent of the original table :

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.V_PriceNodeLookupIndex
AS
SELECT Id, PriceNodeId, ItemId, 
       [1] AS OptionValueId1,
       [2] AS OptionValueId2,
       [3] AS OptionValueId3,
       [4] AS OptionValueId4,
       [5] AS OptionValueId5,
       [6] AS OptionValueId6,
       [7] AS OptionValueId7,
       [8] AS OptionValueId8,
       [9] AS OptionValueId9,
       [10] AS OptionValueId10,
       [11] AS OptionValueId11,
       [12] AS OptionValueId12,
       [13] AS OptionValueId13,
       [14] AS OptionValueId14,
       [15] AS OptionValueId15,
       [16] AS OptionValueId16,
       [17] AS OptionValueId17,
       [18] AS OptionValueId18,
       [19] AS OptionValueId19,
       [20] AS OptionValueId20
FROM   (SELECT PN.Id, PN.PriceNodeId, PN.ItemId, V.Position, V.OptionValue
        FROM   questions_76231541.PriceNodeLookupIndex AS PN
               LEFT OUTER JOIN questions_76231541.PriceNodeLookupIndex_values AS V
                  ON PN.Id = V.Id) AS SRC
PIVOT  (MAX(OptionValue)
        FOR Position IN ( [1],  [2],  [3],  [4],  [5],  [6],  [7],  [8],  [9], [10], 
                         [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20])
       ) AS PV;
GO
```

Comment: It will be great if you populate PriceNodeLookupIndex_values with few dummy data to appear as OptionValueId1,OptionValueId2,OptionValueId3 etc

Comment: I have add the view...

Answer (score 0):

`Itemid` can  good choice for `Clustered Index`.Provided it fullfill certain condition.
Since `Itemid` is not ever increasing ,data can be inserted/updated in any data page.
There may be frequent page split.
But Since `itemid` is `INT` you can fine tune fillfactor to avoid page split.

Why `Clustered index` on `PriceNodeId` ?

If you are not much DBA kind of person then play safe.
Make id as `Clustered index`.

And both `Itemid,PriceNodeId` as `NonClustered Index`.

Good part about your table is that All columns are INT data type.
So it will always perform ok(if not better).

How many rows are there in table ?

How frequnetly this table will be search ?

How you have written your query to achive your requirement ?